# Array instances do not follow the path of the curve

Tags: modifiers

Why do the array instances follow the first path, but on the second path they are on some breaking path? It can be seen in the picture. Both paths are the same, created from a deformed circle.
[image: example]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vk26eQdZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vk26eQdZ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. **The curve and object** that should follow the curve **must have their origins at world origin**.

   - apply the *Location* of the curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode). This will move the origin (orange dot) to the world origin (0,0,0).
   - move the chain segment parts (parent and child in your case) to the world origin. It's easy to do with the 3D cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in *Object* mode)
2. the bad curve has loose segments and a single lost control point in the top left area. It doesn't need to be closed but **the curve must not have any loose parts**. Check it in *Edit* move. Select a control point and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked segments. What will be not selected are the loose segments. Move it a bit to see what's going on (<kbd>G</kbd>).

When the issues are fixed you can set *Fit Type* to `Fit Curve` and select the curve in the *Array* modifier settings. Blender will adjust the length of the array so it fits the curve.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. when you use array and curve modifier make sure both use the same curve - you mixed them up
2. the object and the curve should have both position 0,0,0 -> move them together after it works, not before hand
3. also parent items not before but after you successfully see the right result

[image]

then u get:
[image]

Comment: thx man i just fix my curve and works very well...i dont see that mess...