# How to make long protrusion using sculpting?

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers, sculpting, sculpt

I want to sculpt a neuron using the Blender2.93 version. I am unable to make long protrusions using the sculpting mode. Should I go for modeling instead of sculpting?

I tried both Shake hook or Elastic Deform but it isn't working. The protrusions are supposed to be pretty long to represent a 1-meter axonal length. This is a structure I am referring to in 3D:

[image: structure of neuron]

Another example:
[image: example 2]

Comment: Shake hook or Elastic Deform should work pretty well. How long are the protrusions?

Comment: I tried both but it isn't working. The protrusions are supposed to be pretty long to represent a 1-meter axonal length.  https://byjus.com/biology/neurons/ this is a structure i am referring to in 3D. https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/neuron-3d-max/819986

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case (as in many cases), you're probably best to model the base structure (rough outline, so to speak), and then sculpt the finer details from there.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Comment: ... *or* enable dyntopo to get the inital shape.

Comment: Please don't use only links to external sites but add images directly to your question. The first link is geo-blocked for several countries and unavailable for those readers. Also, add information from your comments to your question because if there are many comments not all are visible immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure is modeled quite simply with a very little modeling, but with some modifiers.

[image: screenshot]

**Axons**; this is basically one object with a *Displacement* modifier and cloud texture + *Array* modifier and *Curve* modifier to make it follow a curve (a Nurbspath in the example)

- create a cylinder, in *Edit* mode, add a few loop cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to have more vertices for the *Displacement* modifier
- create a path, bevel it, and make the Axons follow it with an *Array* and *Curve* modifier (see for example [Array instances do not follow the path of the curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/217686/107598) and  [Problems with Curve Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65567/107598))
- after the two modifiers, add a *Bevel*, a *Subdivision Surface* (level `1` is ok) and *Displacement* modifier. Create a *Cloud* texture for the *Displacement* modifier and adjust the *Scale* (very low, `0.08`) of the *Displacement* modifier and the *Clouds > Size* value of the texture (`0.09`)

**Nerve Endings** are a tree with little spheres as leaves.

- this can be done either with a single vertex (default cube, <kbd>M</kbd> *collapse*) to create a "stick figure tree". Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> the vertex to create the tree and branches. Then add a *Skin* modifier. Adjust the thickness of the branches in *Edit* mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- place spheres for the leaves. If you're lazy, duplicate the tree, and add and apply a *Geometry Node* modifier that uses *Point Instance* to place the spheres. After applying the modifier you can remove the unwanted spheres (hover the mouse pointer over the sphere, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, *Vertices*). The duplication is needed because the *Geometry Nodes* sadly don't work with the *Skin* modifier.

The result is shown at the bottom of the screenshot. The tree in the center has the modifiers applied and unwanted spheres removed. The tree at the top left is a sculpted version.

Alternatively, you can use *Curves* and bevel them, as done for the dendrite.

**Dendrites**; this structure is a "tree" made of *Nurbpaths* to have them more look like "split and bent".

- add a path and make it look like a tree. The branches are separate path segments in the same object because path/curves can't branch in Blender
- increase the *Geometry > Bevel > Depth* value in the *Curve Properties* settings to bevel the curve.
- in *Edit* mode create the pointed ends by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> which sets the radius of the control point to 0.
- then *Object > Convert to Mesh*, and place & scale the branches properly. Scale up the base (*Proportional Editing*) and place the object at the world's origin along the y-axis (that's important for the particle system)

The result is shown at the bottom left in the screenshot, the correct layout in the middle. Make a few variations if you like and move them into a collection.

**Sona**, this is an icosphere (20 faces) with a *Hair Particle System* with the particles rendered as dendrites.

- add a hair particle system, 20 hair or less, select *Emission > Source > Emit From* `Faces` and `1` for *Particles/Face*
- *Render > Render As* `Object` or `Collection`, set *Render > Scale* to `1` and select the `dendrite` object or collection for *Render > Object > Instance Object*
- add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, level 1, to smooth the edges

That's it.

For **Sculpting** you need to convert the hair particles to a mesh (button <kbd>Convert</kbd> at the modifier stack), then apply all modifiers top-down, and join the Sona with the converted particles (look for a new object called *Mesh*). Finally, apply a *Remesh* modifier or use the *Remesh* button in the *Sculpt* mode (does the same). Adjust the *Voxel Size* to preserve the mesh details.

Beware, don't use a too-small value for the *Voxel Size* or Blender will generate millions of vertices and freezes. You can halve the value and test it to determine the correct value safely. If wrong, undo and halve the value again.