# Array instances deform too much on the curve

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

As the title suggests, I have problem with array modifier. Here is what I mean by "deforming"
[image: Look at the size of the rectangle][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O22D.png)Look at the size of the rectangle
[image: And this is how array and curve modifiers deformed it][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpApu.png)And this is how array and curve modifiers deformed it
[image: Sit on this chair is what I'm trying to achieve]Sit on this chair is what I'm trying to achieve

[I Found a post with the same problem, but they didn't have that issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217686/array-instances-do-not-follow-the-path-of-the-curve?newreg=25fbf39f36ee46dfa21c6685ef5d643b)

[image]

Comment: This [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfnfwrmMfJc) (which is actually about making tank tracks!) shows how to array objects around a curve without distortion so may be what you need.